# How to show orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be n*n matrix with complex entries. 
Prove that $AA^*=I$ iff rows of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of $C^n$.

I know since $AA^*=\langle a_i, a_j \rangle= \delta_{i,j}$ so the rows are orthonormal.
But why does it mean that they are basis?

Comment: Basis of a space = set of linearly independent vectors such that every other vector in that space can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors from that set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the rows to be a basis they must be linearly independent but in this case, orthonormality implies linear independence.